# Probability of toasted bread

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Here is the problem:
The time it takes for a baker to bake a loaf of bread without it being underbaked is normally distributed with a mean of µ minutes and a standard deviation of σ minutes. Bread is considered to be slightly baked if it is baked for longer than (µ + 1.5σ) minutes. What is the probability that bread randomly selected by the baker will be slightly toasted?

Possibile answers:
A. 93,32%
B. 69,12%
C. 30,85%
D. 6,68%

I wonder od if it is possibile(and how)to calculate it so I don't have to look at normal distribution curve. I tried to look for some information on the internet but its didn't help.

Comment: I assume that "slightly toasted" is the same as "slightly baked"?  In any case, you'll certainly need to look at the normal distribution to compute the value.  That said, I think it's fairly obvious which of those answers must be the right one  (two of them are absurd, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [empirical rule](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/modeling-distributions-of-data/normal-distributions-library/a/normal-distributions-review) can be applied here.

Remember that in normal distributions (with a random variable $T$ - time to bake a loaf of bread without underbaking it)
$$P(\mu-\sigma<T<\mu+\sigma)\approx0.68$$
$$P(\mu-2\sigma<T<\mu+2\sigma)\approx0.95$$
Now, if you imagine the normal distribution curve in your mind, it is symmetric over the mean $\mu$, so the probabilities of time being outside these ranges (e.g. below $\mu-\sigma$ or above $\mu+\sigma$) are just $1-P(\text{inside these ranges})$, and (because these probabilities are equal due to symmetry) we divide by $2$ to get the probability of time being bigger than the upper bound of these ranges
$$P(T>\mu+\sigma)\approx\frac{1-0.68}{2}\approx0.16\quad(16\%)$$
$$P(T>\mu+2\sigma)\approx\frac{1-0.95}{2}\approx0.025\quad(2.5\%)$$
So, the probability of $T$ being greater than $\mu+1.5\sigma$ has to be between these two percentages. The only answer that applies is D - $6.68\%$.

Hope this helps!